# PHP for loop running more than it should

Tags: php, mysql

I am making an ajax comment system for my website and I am querying my database for any comments with a certain field. I then look and see if the number of returned results is larger than 3, or less than/equal to 3(I have a specific reason for 3). If it is larger than 3, I set a variable = 3 but if it is less than/equal to 3, I set the variable equal to the number of returned rows(`mysql_num_rows()`). I then echo some text before the loop, then I echo the stuff in the loop and then after the loop I echo more stuff. For some reason my for loop is running more than the given times. What is very strange is that it is echoing the same comment 3 times before moving onto the next comment and echoing that 3 times. After the for loop, I have 9 comments in total. This dosn't work with my design as I can only fit 3 comments where I am placing them. My for loop is nested in a few whiles because I need to query multiple times to get to the information I need based on the info I send to the php(specific reason for this also). Another thing, the PHP only echoes the comments 9 times only if the number of returned results is **greater than** 3 works fine if it is less than 3. I have been over this code 50 times but I can't find anything. Maybe you guys can. Heres the code I am using:

---

```
                $comments = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE profid = '".$row['id']."'");
                $numComments = mysql_num_rows($comments);
                $totalCommComments = 0;
                if ($numComments > 0) {
                    if (mysql_num_rows($comments) > 3) {
                        $totalCommComments = 3;
                        echo '
        <div class="comments">
            <div class="commContainer">
                <ul class="'.$totalCommComments.'Comm">';
                        while ($get1 = mysql_fetch_array($comments)) {
                        for ($l = 1;$l<$totalCommComments;$l++) {
                            echo 'STUFF IS ECHOED HERE';
                        }
                        }  
                        echo '
                 </ul>
            </div>
       </div>';
```

---

I know the variable `$totalCommComments` is set to 3 because I can see the class in the `<ul>`.

PS. This isn't the full code, only the relevant code. Everything else is querying different database for other information needed to make this query.

---

**Thank you so much**

Comment: where is the rest of the code

Comment: What is the difference between `$totalCommComments` and `$numComments`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$comments = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE profid = {$row['id']}");
$numComments = mysql_num_rows($comments);
if ($numComments > 0) { ?>
   <div class="comments">
       <div class="commContainer">
           <ul class="shortComments">
               <?php $i = 0;
               while ($i++ < 3 && $get1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($comments)) { ?>
                   <li class='comment'><?=$get1['comment']?></li>
               <?php } ?>
           </ul>
       </div>
   </div>
<?php } ?>
```

try that. You have a lot of redundant code in there

there are a lot of different ways i could continue to edit this, if you let us know what you are trying to do, i can update this code

Comment: I'm not sure, but I *think* the OP wants to limit the number of comments displayed.

Comment: @Josh, it currently limits it to three comments

Comment: +1 Just needed to refresh. My bad. To be honest, the OP should just use the `LIMIT` clause in the query if these comments aren't used elsewhere.

Comment: @Josh I am using this query somewhere else so I only want to go through the first 3 here but in another place I run through all of them.

Comment: @JosephTorraca Well, that makes sense then. :)

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the for in the while statement.,

```
while ($get1 = mysql_fetch_array($comments)) {
                    for ($l = 1;$l<$totalCommComments;$l++) {
                        echo 'STUFF IS ECHOED HERE';
                    }
                    }
```

should just be

```
while ($get1 = mysql_fetch_array($comments)) {

                        echo $get1['whatever'];

                    }
```

this while will loop all the comments automatically, the for you're adding is what's trippling the returned results

Answer (score 0):

$numComments is the number of comments, $totalCommComments might be 0 or 3. You have a while which has $numComments iteration and for each iteration you have a for with either 0 or 3 iterations. This means that you will have $numComments * $totalCommComments iterations, which is perfectly normal.

In my opinion you should have a single loop, where your indexing and loop condition should be corrected.